# Azure jwt token not work after swapping slots

Tags: azure, authentication

I have a two slots for mobile app service at Azure: production and development. Also I have a client app that can work with this mobile service. Application version hosted at production slot does not contain authentication. Application version hosted at development slot has authentication and it works well. So, my client app can get authentication token and access protected API, and work with service hosted at development slot. When I swap this slots, client app still can get authentication token, but can't access protected API. I getting error 401 unauthorized on any attempt to call API using acquired token.

I'm using a custom authentication as described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth)

Both slots is identically configured: authentication: enabled, action to take when request is not authenticated: allow anonymous requests, authentication providers: disabled. As far as I can understand the one and only difference between those slots is URL. It looks like when the url of service is changed, it starts to generate invalid tokens.

That can be a cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the parameters that involved in token creation process is hostname. In my code hostname value was provided from MobileAppSettings. The problem was that MobileAppSettings return the hostname value of development slot after the slots swap, so the generated token is invalid. Service restart fixes this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this question, there are a few additional things to consider when using Azure authentication and slot swap. First, the Azure team has corrected the hostname issue, so all slots have the same hostname (you can verify this in the Environment settings for each slot). Tokens generated on one slot are now completely valid on all other slots.

HOWEVER, when a token is generated, it is stored in a folder on the hard drive of each slot, and that folder is not sticky to a specific slot. This means that if you have client users using a token for your production slot and you swap production and staging slots, that client's token WON'T be valid anymore (because their token reference that was on the production slot is now on the staging slot).

This may or may not be an issue for your app. If you require users to log in frequently, then they may not even notice the extra need to login. If however you have long lasting tokens (like most social networking sites) then this can cause some headaches.

Comment: Headaches does not even begin to describe the effect it has on me... Did any solution come up in the 5 years that have passed?